# Orchard CMS Manage Content page not showing details

Tags: orchardcms

In C# code, I created a custom content type (a RSVP type for replies). When items are created, they do indeed show up in the content item listing on the admin page.

But as you can see below , none of the details are listed like they are for other types like Page. How can I get details like Name (the name of the person RSVP'ing) to show up. I created tokens for use in workflows but that hasn't had any effect in these regards. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Use placement.info with pieces like `DisplayType="SummaryAdmin"`